# VSCode running "yo code" gives me an ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, node-modules, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to make a custom extension in vscode, but every time I run the command `yo code` (from the [vscode tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)) I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'stream' imported from C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\mem-fs\dist\index.js
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:655:9)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:696:18)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36)
```

Even when I followed the steps from the [yoeman guide](https://yeoman.io/authoring/) I get the same error. I'm not very familiar with node or npm sop I don't know what to search for or do.

Additional information:
OS: `Windows 11`
Terminal: `Powershell`
Generator Location: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-code`
Happy to provide any more inmformation required.

I've tried running it from multiple drives, reinstalling the package, and tying it with another generator.